# Sequence files in OpenCV C++

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, video-processing

I was dealing with the Caltech Pedestrian Dataset and had to use the .seq (sequence) files for extracting frames in openCV C++.

As an alternative, I was looking to convert the .seq files to .avi, but have not been able to that. (P.S. Looking at the help forums has not given me the results)

Comment: if you're using opencv3.0, there's a loader for caltech sequences in the opencv_contrib/datasets module.

Comment: Is there no other option for opencv2 version?
Or to convert .seq file to video format (avi preferably)?

Comment: just look at the code, and adapt it ?

Comment: Am trying to do so. Having some glitches. Thanks for the help however!